# Charge a 12V marine/boat battery with AC

Tags: batteries, 12v

need to build a diode bridge to recharge a battery (car/boat type) from a boat engine that gives 12V AC.
I thought of doing something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJrsST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Only I can't know which diode I have to buy and which capacitor to take.

Can you help me?

Comment: You need something like 13.5 V to 13.8 V to charge a lead acid battery. What voltaage is delivered by your charger? 1N4148 diodes are not suitable.

Comment: We need way more information, where does the 12v AC come from and what is its current capacity? What size battery and what loads are you connecting to it? It sounds like a dynamo which if the case it is designed to work with a off the shelf regulator/rectifier.

Comment: The alternator on most marine and automotive engines produces DC, and is intended to be connected directly to a 12 volt lead-acid battery.  Are you sure your the charging source on your engine produces AC?

Comment: You cannot simply connect a battery to a generator, even with a rectifier.  Practical systems have voltage or charge regulating circuitry in there somewhere, often controlling the alternator itself via the field coils.  You need to consult those having *domain knowledge* of engine charging systems ideally for your particular engine - ie, your boatyard's mechanic or a boating forum, or the engine's manual - try searching for that online perhaps you will be lucky and someone scanned it.

Comment: This will damage your battery. Though the upside is that those puny 1N4148s will fry pretty much instantly, so you won't damage your battery _too_ much.

Comment: You don't really need a filtering capacitor when you charge lead acid batteries. The battery itself doesn't particularly mind pulsed DC. In addition you probably want a cutof circuit that cuts charging when battery is fully charged.